# popViewController while pushViewController is animating resulting in corrupted navigation bar

Tags: ios, animation, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I have a situation in my app where a navigation controller `pushViewController:animated:YES` is triggered by a user. The user can also trigger a `popViewController:animated:YES` by tapping another control. The intent is that the `popViewController` is the undo or inverse of the pushViewController.

However, if the user triggers the `popViewController:animated:YES` **while the pushViewController animation is still happening**, I get a message logged to the console:

```
2014-08-22 08:26:36.601 MyApp[22380:60b] nested pop animation can result in corrupted    navigation bar
2014-08-22 08:26:36.960 MyApp[22380:60b] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
```

And indeed, the navigation bar does get corrupted: the back button is no longer visible. I have to go do something else then come back to the affected page in my app to get it working properly again.

What can I do to avoid this race condition? My first thought was protect the `popViewController` call with a check to see if a current navigation animation is already occurring, and waiting for that to finish (or even canceling the `popViewController` call completely). However, I haven't been able to find a way of detecting that an action is already occurring.

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: @MohitPopat No, this is entirely programmatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions to this problem. I suggest you to implement first one.

1 . Avoid user interaction on multiple controls at a time by setting exclusive touch to them.

- Set exclusiveTouch property to YES for those controls if they shares superView(parent view) else you will have to set this property YES to their parent views.

2 . Implement UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol in that view controller where user is tapping multiple controls at a time.

```
 – navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:
 – navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:
```

Set a flag when first delegate method gets called & reset it in second. Use this flag on every push/pop operation.